# Cursor Adapter loading list bottom to top for chat application

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I am working on a chat application and i am using cursor adapter to display the chat list. The chats are backed up on a server and we have load more chats feature which allows user to get his last 50 chats from the server.

This loadmore button is on top of the list.

So when i add these new chats to my database and swap the cursor to reload the listview, the listview scroll position is not maintained and the list goes to the top which is not the correct behavior. I want to maintain the listview scroll position just like it happens in whatsapp chat when the load more chat button is pressed.

I managed to maintain the scroll position using this code by using setSelectionFromTop method :

```
int firstVisibleItem = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View view = chatList.getChildAt(0);
int pos = (view == null ? 0 : view.getBottom());
// swap cursor to reload the list
listView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem + addedItemsCount + 1, pos);
```

but when i do this the listview gives me a slight glitch which may be due to the fact that listview scroll position goes to top first and then comes back down to my selected position.

I want the listview to simply only render new items alone from bottom to top while maintaining the scroll position like it happens in whatsapp with out any glitch.

I have also used listviews stackfrombottom method but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help regarding this would be great help. Looking for a detailed approach to render the listview from bottomToTop while maintaining its scroll position.

Thanks.

Comment: what you want to achieve is done by default, all you need is to make sure `notifyDataSetChanged` to be called

Comment: its done by default when when you're making the list render top to bottom like in a contact list, i don't think its the case when when you're want items to populate from bottom to top.
Link to a working example would be extremely helpful, thank you

Comment: Ah sorry i missed that

Comment: no worries, doing more research on this.

Answer (score 2):

So i managed to fixed my problem, it turns out that listView always starts laying its elements from top to bottom, so to hold the cursor position you must explicitly specify the position of your selected item by using setSelectionFromTop method of listView like this :-

```
int firstVisibleItem = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View view = chatList.getChildAt(0);
int pos = (view == null ? 0 : view.getBottom());
// swap cursor to reload the list
listView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem + addedItemsCount + 1, pos);
```

but this will give you a slight fliker(since the list would start from top and you would again drag it back down) which would look very bad. So to overcome that situation we need to block listview from laying out its items.

I stumbled upon a great article by chris banes explaining how to do it.[Here is link](http://chris.banes.me/2013/02/21/listview-keeping-position/)

to block the listView to lay its children we need to override its layoutChildren method.
public class BlockingListView extends ListView {

```
private boolean mBlockLayoutChildren;

public BlockingListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setBlockLayoutChildren(boolean block) {
    mBlockLayoutChildren = block;
}

@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    if (!mBlockLayoutChildren) {
        super.layoutChildren();
    }
}
```

}

and then do 
    listView.setBlockLayoutChildren(true);

```
int firstVisibleItem = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View view = chatList.getChildAt(0);
int pos = (view == null ? 0 : view.getBottom());
// swap cursor to reload the list or notifyDataSetChange for BaseAdapter
listView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem + addedItemsCount + 1, pos);

listView.setBlockLayoutChildren(false)
```

this way we can stop the listView from glitching and it gives us a seamless bottom to top scrolling experience while loading items continuously like we have in famous chat applications like whatsApp and slack etc etc.